# QGIS 2.14 How to save and load parameter values in Batch Processing Tool

Tags: qgis-2.14

Am relatively new to QGIS, I am trying to save a query I carry out frequently using the Batch Processing - Extract by location tool. For example with the following parameters:
[image]

I then want to save these parameters so I can use them next time rather than add in and tick all the boxes etc etc because all the parameters stay the same pretty much. So I go to the Save function under parameters and save. But when I go to reload  the layers all appear with quotation marks which makes running the search invalid. What am I doing wrong?
[image: after loading the save criteria]